# cannot load such file -- spec_helper.rb

Tags: rspec

Total Linux and pragramming noob here. I'm doing the Odin project, and I am currently working through codeschool's rspec tutorial. 
Whenever I try to run my spec files I get this error message:

rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper.rb (LoadError).

I have looked through other answers to similair problems, but nothing have worked so far. I have tried setting the required path to relative in bot my spec_helper.rb file and in my spec file. I have tried executing the rspec command from root directory and project directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
I'm sure I am missing something really simple.

Comment: So...if I remove the require line from my spec file, the spec file runs. The spec helper file is located one folder above the spec file: spec/spec_helper.rb  and spec file is located in spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb
This is the exact same setup as in the tutorial, where require 'spec_helper' works just fine...... just not for me

Comment: There is almost certainly something wrong with your test setup. The `spec_helper` file is made available automatically by RSpec, which prepends your projects `spec` directory to the front of the load path.

Comment: I've tried re-initiating the setup lots of times. By doing rspec --init, deleting and re creating all the files. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you are requiring the spec_helper and it can't find it.
Try this to start project and see if you have any problems.

```
$ mkdir test_proj && cd test_proj
$ rspec --init
```

Now running rspec on the spec directory (inside test_proj) should yield the correct output.

```
$ rspec spec/
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue I was having and the file now runs. There's only one weird thing. When I run my spec file from the test_proj directory, the file runs twice.